# Compiled application does not work in it's own folder

Tags: c#, winforms

The application that I've released works very well in any folder, except:

```
E:\Csharp\NewMacaron\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Release
```

That's the release folder.

The following error is produced:

[image]

Comment: You have missed or corrupted config file in that folder.

Comment: When realesing new application olds are erased and new ones are created. I did nothing here. Execpt when new apllication is realeased, i move the exe file in another folder don't touch the others. That can be because there is a bug in c# 2008 ? I will retry to re-install c# 2008

Comment: I would re-install Visual C# 2008 only as a last resort... I honestly don't think it has anything to do with that.  Just `Clean` and `Rebuild` your solution.

Comment: @B.K what do you mean clean and rebuild the solution. After any correction I rebuild the solution but since 3 hours the exe file would not work ONLY in it's own folder. Elsewhere it works.

Comment: There is a project option 'clean project'.

Comment: I copied all the files from release folder in another folder and I begin delete and test when it will works.
It's worked after deleting macaron.exe.manifest
Any idea

Comment: As the macaron.exe.manifest is created by the c# application each time we did a changement there must be a problem with 2008

Answer (score 1):

There is no bug in VS 2008 in regards to the issue you're experiencing.  You somehow corrupted your manifest file or **most likely**, the config file (`macaron.exe.config`).  The likely cause is that it contains invalid XML and it hasn't been overridden by a default version.

First, try this:

`BUILD` > `Clean Solution`; `BUILD` > `Rebuild Solution`.  In that order.

If that doesn't fix the issue, you need to look into your `*.config` file and check to make sure that you didn't leave off a closing bracket or have an extra quotation mark in there somewhere.  If there is no sensitive information, post your configuration file contents in your original post, so that we may check it for errors.

Last, but not least, if you're still having issues, there could be a possibility of the specified `.NET` framework incompatibility with the machine or some of the references you're using, as specified in the config file.  Since it is  specified in the `*.config` file and it may be off from what you're working with, it could propagate into the error you're seeing.  I am not sure if you've created that project on your current machine or if you've imported it from somewhere else, but it maybe that you need to go into your project properties and change the `.NET` framework version to your desired target version.  This will override the supported runtime in the configuration file.  The reason you may not be seeing the error in other directories could be due to the fact that you're not copying the configuration file (we don't know, since we don't know everything you're doing).

Comment: I tried what you said. I still have the same error. About the .NET it was working till I made a change in tab <UPDATE PUBLISHING>. However I disabled it but the error still remains. I have .NET 3.5, and the application is developping since 2 months on this machine without error. But 2 months ago it was on a WIN7  with .NET 4.5.1.
When I erase Config.Exe and manifest application starts on it's own release folder.